# Why is overleaf unable to locate my file sections in the path? I'm trying to get my word count

Tags: overleaf, paths, word-count

[image]

This is what I see when I click the word count button. This was someone else's template I used from overleaf.
[image]

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address (including the project's URL if it's ok for us to see what you're working on) and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: I'm still new at all of this so I'm not entirely sure what you mean @DavidCarlisle. All those file sections are mentioned in the main.tex part of the document. This is someone else's template so I'm not sure where to find everything on it either.

Comment: I have added a new picture is that more helpful @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Yes thanks it confirms that it is not the most obvious thing, so I leave you to Tom who will be able to trace what is happening

Comment: Thanks for the help @DavidCarlisle

Comment: The chapter name can be case sensitive too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Tom from Overleaf support speaking.)

This is caused by the main file not being in the top folder of the project. Unfortunately, `texcount` and other external tools like `minted` etc. fail when the main file is in a subfolder.

So simply moving all the files one folder up should solve the issue. Just please do remember to hit Recompile afterwards and wait for the compilation to finish -- without that the word count still won't work.

Comment: Is there any chance that Overleaf would consider implementing it such that it runs at wherever the main file has been specified? (I'm working on a deeply nested project that it would be a real pain to restructure)

Comment: @DannyGarside Thanks for asking. We actually looked into this a few times, and it's not rocket science, but we haven't found a way of doing it that wouldn't break some of our existing projects that (exactly the opposite of what would be useful here) rely on the way we run the compile. So sorry for not being able to bring positive news, but I don't really see this changing in a reasonable future...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Overleaf, but may give some hints about how TeXcount handles paths to included files.

By default, TeXcount expects paths to be relative to the current directory (same as options `-dir=.`): ie the directory from which TeXcount is run. As I recall, this is the behaviour you get when you run TeX/LaTeX from the command line.

If you want paths to be relative to the main document, you can run TeXcount with the option `-dir` (without any value).

It's a while since I checked this, so I just hope the [documentation](https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/documentation.html) is still correct.