# Overleaf won't show my word count. Says that it cannot find my files

Tags: overleaf, word-count

When I try checking my word count, I keep encountering this error.

```
!!! File Chapters/Chapter1 not found in path [./]. !!!
!!! File Chapters/Chapter2 not found in path [./]. !!!
!!! File Chapters/Chapter3 not found in path [./]. !!!
!!! File Appendices/AppendixA not found in path [./]. !!!
!!! File Appendices/AppendixB not found in path [./]. !!!
!!! Encountered \end without corresponding \begin !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for \end. !!!
!!! Environment ended while waiting for nd{document}. !!!
```

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577523/why-is-overleaf-unable-to-locate-my-file-sections-in-the-path-im-trying-to-get) question and tried doing as the person from Overleaf suggested and put all my files in my main folder.

My folder was like this:

```
Latex
  Chapters
     Chapter1
     Chapter2
     etc
  Appendices
     Appendix1
     Appendix2
  main.tex
```

Now it's like this:

```
Latex
  Chapter1
  Chapter2
  Appendix1
  Appendix2
  main.tex
```

Latex is the folder with everything in it. I recompiled, but I am still getting the same error. Does anyone know any other fixes for this?

Comment: This seems to be a very overleaf specific questions. Please note, questions which are not really (La)TeX questions but questions about using overleaf are usually not on-topic. It is recommended to ask the Overleaf support directly.

Comment: if your files are all in the main folder then clearly Chapters/Chapter1  won;t be found but you are giving very few clues about what you are doing and it seems to be overleaf specific so not really anything we can help with here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Overleaf, but it uses TeXcount which I do know.

TeXcount by default expects file paths to be relative to the current working directory. I suspect Overleaf runs TeXcount from a different working directory, but with the full path to the TeX file specified.

TeXcount has an option `-dir` which can be used to specify the folder relative to which file paths should be given. The default is `-dir=.`, but an alternative is just `-dir` in which case the folder of the main document is used.

As I understand from Marijn's comment, the word count feature does allow the TeXcount options to be changed. However, there is documentation on [how to run TeXcount on Overleaf with custom options](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/customising-texcount/dqvrqghbtmbc). If this approach still works, it should be possible to set the `-dir` options.

Some TeXcount options and settings can be modified from within the document itself, but unfortunately the `-dir` option is not one of them.

---

Actually, if I'm correct in assuming Overleaf runs TeXcount from a different working directory, the best solution is to get Overleaf to change the options they use when calling TeXcount.

Comment: On Overleaf you cannot change the options to TeXcount. There is a button in the interface that you can press and that's it. It is possible to run programs with command line arguments through the `shellesc` or `bashful` packages or through the Lua `io` library, but if the document is in a subdirectory then that also doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Marijn: That makes things more difficult. I'll update my answer, and try to add some references, although they may be outdated.